# ¿Como hacer una instancia a un constructor que recibe un arreglo como parámetro?

Tags: java, android, adapter

Tengo un problema al intentar hacer una instancia a un constructor de una clase, tengo dos clases, una extiende de un `DialogFragment` y se llama Dialogo y la otra es una clase llamada `ServicioArchivo`, el error que me muestra es el siguiente:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.example.enriq.myapplication.adapter.NotaAdapter.setNotas(android.app.Activity,
>   java.util.List)' on a null object reference

anteriormente ya habia tenido un error similar y lo solucione de la siguiente forma:

> servicio = new ServicioArchivo(getActivity());
>                           servicio.onClickGuardarPersona(matricula.getText().toString(),clienesillo.getText().toString());

con esta solucion que me ayudaron a realizar se soluciono un problema similar al que tengo ahorita, he intentado aplicar esta solucion al error que actualmente tengo pero no encuentro la forma de eviatar que me arroje un NullPointerException.

Esta es la clase Dialogo, en la linea de codigo que dice **servicio.onClickGuardarPersona** se llama al metod que esta en mi otra clase:

```
package com.example.enriq.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.enriq.myapplication.adapter.NotaAdapter;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by Enriq on 30/01/2018.
 */

public class Dialogo extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {
    private ArrayList<Registro_parqueo> lista;
    private String archivo = "parquimetro.obj";

    private String notas="";
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "notas.txt";
    View view;

    private RecyclerView notasRecyclerView;
    private EditText editNota;
    private NotaAdapter adapter;
    //private ServicioArchivo servicio = new ServicioArchivo(getActivity());
    private ServicioArchivo servicio;


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        View MyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null);
        final EditText matricula = (EditText)MyView.findViewById(R.id.parqueo);
        final EditText clienesillo = (EditText)MyView.findViewById(R.id.cliente);

        builder.setView(MyView)
                .setPositiveButton("Registrar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        servicio = new ServicioArchivo(getActivity());
                        servicio.onClickGuardarPersona(matricula.getText().toString(),clienesillo.getText().toString());

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Dialogo.this.getDialog().cancel();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

Esta es mi clase ServicioArchivo, en esta clase el metodo **onClickGuardarPersona** es el que ejecuta una linea de codigo para enviar datos al arreglo que esta en mi clase NotaAdapter, esta es la linea de codigo que me da el error: **adapter.setNotas(Arrays.asList(leerNotas()));**, ya rebise si no estoy enviando valores nulos pero no es el caso.

```
package com.example.enriq.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.enriq.myapplication.adapter.NotaAdapter;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by Next University.
 */
public class ServicioArchivo  {

    private Activity activity;
    private String notas="";
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "notas.txt";
    private NotaAdapter adapter;

    public ServicioArchivo(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;

    }

    public void onClickGuardarPersona(String matricula, String clienesillo) {

        try {
            //* Inicializar
            String nota= matricula+"\n"+clienesillo;
            agregarNota(nota);
            Log.i("myTag", "para el arreglo tenemos esto: "+matricula+" "+clienesillo);
            //adapter = new NotaAdapter(activity, Arrays.asList(leerNotas()));

            adapter.setNotas(Arrays.asList(leerNotas()));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.i("myTag", "La nota se guardo, estamos en el onClickGuardarPersona");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("myTag", "Tenemos un error al guardar");
        }
    }


    public void agregarNota(String nota) throws IOException {
        notas = notas.concat("".equals(notas) ? "" : ";");
        notas = notas.concat(nota);
        Log.i("myTag", "Estamos en el metodo agregarNota()");
        guardar();

    }

    public String[] leerNotas() throws IOException {
        cargar();
        Log.i("myTag", "Estamos en leer nota");
        return notas.split(";");
    }

    public String leerNotas(int posicion) throws IOException {
        cargar();
        String[] listaNotas = notas.split(";");
        return listaNotas[posicion];
    }

    private void guardar() throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fos = activity.openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(notas.getBytes());
        Log.i("myTag", "Estamos en el metodo guardar()");
        fos.close();

    }

    private void cargar() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = activity.openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
        Log.i("myTag", "Estamos en el metodo cargar()");
        int c;
        notas = "";
        while ( (c = fis.read()) != -1) notas += String.valueOf((char)c);
        fis.close();
    }

    public void eliminar(){
        activity.deleteFile(FILE_NAME);
        notas="";
    }
}
```

Esta es mi clase NotaAdapter:

```
package com.example.enriq.myapplication.adapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.enriq.myapplication.R;
import com.example.enriq.myapplication.adapter.NotaViewHolder;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Next University.
 */
public class NotaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotaViewHolder> {

    private List<String> notas;
    private Activity activity;

    public NotaAdapter(Activity activity, List<String> notas) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.notas = notas;
    }

    @Override
    public NotaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notas_item,parent,false);

        return new NotaViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NotaViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindNota(notas.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notas.size();
    }

    public Activity getActivity() {
        return activity;
    }

    public List<String> getNotas() {
        return notas;
    }

    public void setNotas(List<String> notas) {
        this.notas = notas;
    }
}
```

Comment: Que error obtienes?

Comment: @Jorgesys el siguiente error al querer mandar datos a mi arreglo.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.enriq.myapplication.adapter.NotaAdapter.setNotas(android.app.Activity, java.util.List)' on a null object reference

Comment: Es correcto tu método y los valores que le envias @kikehatake el problema es que debes inicializar el adapter : adapter = new NotaAdapter(activity, Arrays.asList(leerNotas()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu método recibe un `ArrayList` de `Strings`:

```
public void setNotas(List<String> notas) {
    this.notas = notas;
}
```

**Lo que realizas es correcto**, de hecho leerNotas() obtiene un array de Strings y es convertido mediante Arrays.asList() a un ArrayList que es lo que necesita el método `setNotas()`

```
adapter.setNotas(Arrays.asList(leerNotas()));
```

---

El problema en realidad es que la instancia de `Adapter` tiene valor null por eso obtienes el error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'void
>   com.example.enriq.myapplication.adapter.NotaAdapter.setNotas(android.app.Activity,
>   java.util.List)' on a null object reference

debes inicializar el `adapter`, de hecho el constructor ya recibe el ArrayList de valores y no necesitas llamar nuevamente `setNotas()` :

```
adapter = new NotaAdapter(activity, Arrays.asList(leerNotas()));    
//adapter.setNotas(Arrays.asList(leerNotas()));
```

Código:

```
public void onClickGuardarPersona(String matricula, String clienesillo) {

        try {
            //* Inicializar
            String nota= matricula+"\n"+clienesillo;
            agregarNota(nota);
            Log.i("myTag", "para el arreglo tenemos esto: "+matricula+" "+clienesillo);

            adapter = new NotaAdapter(activity, Arrays.asList(leerNotas()));    
            //adapter.setNotas(Arrays.asList(leerNotas()));

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.i("myTag", "La nota se guardo, estamos en el onClickGuardarPersona");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("myTag", "Tenemos un error al guardar");
        }
    }
```

---

**Actualización:**
Si lo que deseas es que al dar click se vean los cambios, entonces tienes que inicializar el `Adapter` al instanciar el Servicio:

```
public ServicioArchivo(Activity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
    adapter = new NotaAdapter(activity, Arrays.asList(leerNotas()));  
}
```

Comment: Esa solucion ya la habia intentado y en efecto asi no muestra error, pero el problema es que si lo uso de esa manera no me actualiza la lista de registros que tengo.

Comment: Lo hice como mensionas pero no funciona el metodo de notifyDataSetChanged(); tengo entendido que es un metodo de los RecyclerView

Comment: Revisa la actualización, inicializa el adapter antes y al dar click solo cambias los valores.

Comment: tambien puedes mandar a llamar notifyDataSetChanged de tu adapter, para que se actualice la vista

Comment: @Jorgesys lo que comentaste ayer fue correcto, la solucion que me diste muchas gracias, el problema por el que no se actualizaba el recyclerview lo soluciones agregando estas tres lineas de codigo:

notasRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            notasRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            notasRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(activity, 3));

Con esto se actualizo mi recyclerview

Comment: setHasFixedSize(true); es importante para que se vean los resultados en el REcyclerView, excelente Kike, saludos!